# howto use fatfree php framework without rewrite engine

Tags: .htaccess, fat-free-framework

I'm not able to use an htaccess for my project therefore clean URLs doesn't work for routing. Is there a way to to use query params instead?

**example**

`myf3project.net/user/show` isn't possible. Instead I want to do something like this:

- `myf3project.net?path=user/show` or
- `myf3project.net?view=user&action=show`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also overwrite the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for this purpose:

```
$f3->route('GET /user', function ($f3) { echo "user"; });
$f3->route('GET /user/@action',function($f3,$params){ 
  echo "user->".$params['action']; 
});

if ($f3->exists('GET.path',$path))
    $f3->URI = $f3->BASE.'/'.$path;

$f3->run();
```

and then just open 
`http://myf3project.net?path=user/show`

Comment: Thx! That's the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that `mod_rewrite` is not available? That's a problem indeed. You can however call [$f3->mock](http://fatfreeframework.com/base#mock) to the rescue.

Here's a quick example:

```php
$f3 = require('lib/base.php');

// Homepage
$f3->route('GET /',function($f3){
    echo 'This is home. '.
        'Click <a href="?path=/contact">here</a> to see the contact form.';
});

// Contact form
$f3->route('GET|POST /contact',function($f3){
    echo 'This is the contact form. '.
        'Click <a href="?path=/">here</a> to go back home.'.
        '<form method="post" action="">'.
        '<textarea name="message"></textarea>'.
        '<button>Send message</button></form>';
    if ($f3->VERB=='POST')
        echo 'Submitted message:<br>'.
            nl2br($f3->get('POST.message'));
});

// Workaround here: $f3->mock is used instead of $f3->run
$path=$f3->get('GET.path');
if (@$path[0]!=='/')
    $path='/';
$f3->mock($f3->VERB.' '.$path,$_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's still kinda possible, unfortunately you have to build most on your own.

Very basic example:

```
<?php

$f3 = require 'lib/base.php';

$f3->route('GET /', function() use($f3) {
    switch($f3->get('view')) {
        case 'user':
            // do something
            break;
        case 'admin':
            // do something
            break;
    }
});
```

The "/" route should work even without .htaccess.

Comment: Hi sascha, I changed `$f3->get('view')` to `$f3->get('GET.view')`. Now it works. Thx!

Comment: You're right, forgot to add that to my code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@xfra35's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32395288/1697454), I propose a solution that will allow you to have paths like this:

`/index.php/foo/bar`

Instead of:

`/index.php?path=/foo/bar`

But you still can use query variables (like `/index.php/foo/bar?test=123`) and get them using `$_GET['test']` or `$f3->get('GET.test')`:

Just replace your `$f3->run();` with:

```
$path=$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
if (@$path[0]!=='/')
    $path='/';
$f3->mock($f3->VERB.' '.$path.'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_POST);
```